# Button to start the Gallery on Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, gallery

I'm trying to make a button in my App open the built in gallery.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentBrowseFiles = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intentBrowseFiles.setType("image/*");
                intentBrowseFiles.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intentBrowseFiles);                   
            }
```

This results in an error message "The application Camera (process com.android.gallery) has stopped unexpectedly."

If I set the Intent action to ACTION_GET_CONTENT it manages to open the gallery but then simply returns the image to my app when a picture is selected which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to make a button in my App open the built in browser.

Your question subject says "Gallery". Your first sentence in the question says "browser". These are not the same thing.

> If I set the Intent action to ACTION_GET_CONTENT it manages to open the gallery but then simply returns the image to my app when a picture is selected which is not what I want.

Of course, actually telling us "what [you] want" would just be too useful, so you are making us guess.

I am going to go out on a limb and guess that you are trying to open the Gallery application just as a normal application. Note that there is no Gallery application in the Android OS. There may or may not be a Gallery application on any given device, and it may or may not be one from the Android open source project.

However, for devices that have the Android Market on them, they should support an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` with a MIME type obtained from `android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE`.

Comment: yes sorry, the I meant to write the gallery. 
"I'm trying to make a button in my App open the built in" -gallery- is what I am trying to do. But maby I wasn't clear on that I want it to open normally.

Comment: I have encountered a problem with this approach. The button with the above settings (ACTION_VIEW and the MIME type) works well on the emulator, but crashes when I upload it to my HTC Hero (even though it has Android Market on it).

Comment: @Christopher Käck: The reason I wrote "for devices that have the Android Market on them" is that they should support that Intent to comply with the Compatibility Definition Document (CDD). You need to comply with the CDD to get the Android Market. Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your crash. It's possible there's a bug in the Hero, but we'd need the stack trace to know for sure.