# Open gallery app from Android Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm looking for a way to open the `Android` gallery application from an intent.

I do not want to return a picture, but rather just open the gallery to allow the user to use it as if they selected it from the launcher (`View pictures/folders`).

I have tried to do the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

However this is causing the application to close once I select a picture (I know this is because of the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`), but I need to just open the gallery.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: This should answer your question...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4979492/1620738

Comment: What's your minSdkVersion version?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
ACTION_VIEW
```

Change your code to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This is the only answer that answers the question! He just needs to *I need to just open the gallery.* not pick or return nada

Comment: This answer is what I was looking for, I have also implemented same code in one of my app but it crashes in some devices :-(

Comment: How to open pictures folder in gallary by using this intent, can you please help me.

Answer (score 34):

I hope this will help you. This code works for me.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
 startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

*ResultCode is used for updating the selected image to Gallery View*

```
if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() < 1) {
            return; // no cursor or no record. DO YOUR ERROR HANDLING
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

        if(columnIndex < 0) // no column index
            return; // DO YOUR ERROR HANDLING

        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

        cursor.close(); // close cursor

        photo = decodeFilePath(picturePath.toString());

        List<Bitmap> bitmap = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        bitmap.add(photo);
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(
                AddIncidentScreen.this, bitmap);
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        newTagImage.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the cursor be closed?

Comment: picturePath is null in my case (android 7.0).

Comment: Couldn't import decodeFilePath(). Used BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathname) instead.

Answer (score 17):

You can open gallery using following intent:

```
public static final int RESULT_GALLERY = 0;

Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent , RESULT_GALLERY );
```

If you want to get result URI or do anything else use this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case QuestionEntryView.RESULT_GALLERY :
        if (null != data) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            //Do whatever that you desire here. or leave this blank

        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Tested on Android 4.0+

Comment: Thank you so much for this :)

Answer (score 7):

1. Following can be used in Activity or Fragment.

   ```
    private File mCurrentPhoto;
   ```
2. Add permissions

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
   ```
3. Add Intents to open "image-selector" and "photo-capture"

   ```
   //A system-based view to select photos.
   private void dispatchPhotoSelectionIntent() {
   Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
           android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
   this.startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_SELECTOR);
   }



       //Open system camera application to capture a photo.
       private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
   Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
   if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(App.Instance.getPackageManager()) != null) {
       try {
           createImageFile();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           // Error occurred while creating the File
       }
       // Continue only if the File was successfully created
       if (mCurrentPhoto != null) {
           takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mCurrentPhoto));
           startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
       }
   }
   }
   ```
4. Add handling when getting photo.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   switch (requestCode) {
   case REQUEST_IMAGE_SELECTOR:
       if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
           String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
           Cursor cursor = App.Instance.getContentResolver().query(data.getData(), filePathColumn, null, null, null);
           if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() < 1) {
               mCurrentPhoto = null;
               break;
           }
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
           if(columnIndex < 0) { // no column index
               mCurrentPhoto = null;
               break;
           }
           mCurrentPhoto = new File(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
           cursor.close();
       } else {
           mCurrentPhoto = null;
       }
       break;
   case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
       if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
           mCurrentPhoto = null;
       }
       break;
   }
   if (mCurrentPhoto != null) {
       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) [parent].findViewById(R.id.loaded_iv);
       Picasso.with(App.Instance).load(mCurrentPhoto).into(imageView);
   }
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }
   ```

Comment: Is permission really required to open the gallery. I didn't have to use any permissions to open the gallery.

Comment: @IsharaAmarasekera if not crash and everything ok for you, then not

Answer (score 5):

As you don't want a result to return, try following simple code.

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

if somebody still getting the error, even after adding the following code

```js
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

then you might be opening the intent in another class (by calling) due to this the app will crash when you click the button.

**SOLUTION FOR THE PROBLEM**

**Put intent in the class file which is connected to the button's layout file.**
for example- **activity_main.xml** contains the button and it is connected to **MainActivity.java file**. but due to fragmentation, you are defining the intent in some other class(lets says Activity.java) then your app will crash **unless you place the intent in MainActivity.java file.** I was getting this error and it is resolved by this.