# Force certain app to receive the intent (not chooser)

Tags: android

I want to use the user to select an image using the default gallery app. I don't want him to choose between apps, I want the default app to open.

I use this code

```
intent = new Intent();
                 intent.setType("image/*");
                 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                 startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

but it keeps showing me list of apps to choose from. Can  I force it to go default ( Gallery app) all the time?

Thank you

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18780533/794088

Comment: If your users want to pick an image from some other app, please let them.

Comment: I'm really glad that Android does not permit this.  I will choose what apps I use, not you!

Comment: The reason is, because I want to know what image they picked. The gallery app returns a path, but if the user choose another app, I dont know how to get the image they picked

Comment: You get the image the same way you get anything from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`: via the `Uri` in the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()`. "The gallery app returns a path" -- no, it does not. It returns a `Uri`. That `Uri` should be a `content://` `Uri`. It does not have to resolve to an actual file anywhere that you can reach (e.g., the image is in a database, the image is in internal storage, the image is on removable storage). Moreover, there are thousands of Android device models, containing dozens, if not hundreds, of "gallery apps", not just one.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I  meant URI (I always think of it as a file which is wrong I guess). So if someone selects an image using "file manager" or any other 3rd party app, I will always be getting URI in the OnActivityResult? If thats the case then no need for forcing the user

Comment: @Snake why don't you try yourself and see what other apps give?