# makeMainSelectorActivity is undefined

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, undefined

For my application, I want it so that when a user clicks a button, they are taken to the built-in Gallery app. Below is the code I have for that method. I would like to use of makeMainSelectorActivity, however it says its undefined for type intent. I also changed the targed and min sdk to 15 and cleansed the project, but nothing changed. Also in LogCat, it says "No Actovity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.APP_GALLERY }. Am I missing something else to get this to work?

MainActivity.java

```
private void goToGallery(){
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=15){        
        Intent intent = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, "android.intent.category.APP_GALLERY");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);//Min SDK 15
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.APP_GALLERY");//Min SDK 8
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}//end goToGallery
```

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been asked. If you haven't already tried, please try:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
Main.this.startActivity(intent);
```

If that does not work, you may try other answers as given:

[How to open an album in Gallery app using an intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498717/how-to-open-an-album-in-gallery-app-using-an-intent)

[Open gallery app from Android Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928727/open-gallery-app-from-android-intent)

[Button to start the Gallery on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979075/button-to-start-the-gallery-on-android/4979492#4979492)

Hope it helps.